# How do I remove some commit messages from my PR on github

Tags: git, github

I have forked a repo and made some changes
on master. Then I made a PR to commit to the original repo.

Before committing, I updating my fork with the origin branch by merging using github UI.

Now my PR includes message form that merge which looks like this:

```
Merge pull request #1 from x/master  …


Merge pull request #4 from x/master  …


My feature
```

How do I get rid of the `Merge pull request` messages in my PR?

Comment: As far as I know the pull request contains your commits, so, theoretically, removing the unnecessary commits (https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html) should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way for removing the wrong commit instead of undoing changes with a revert commit.

1. `git checkout my-pull-request-branch`
2. `git rebase -i HEAD~n` // where n is the number of last commits you want to 
     include in interactive  rebase.
3. Replace pick with drop for commits you want to discard.
4. Save and exit.
5. `git push --force`

Code example is as follow..

```
# Checkout the desired branch
git checkout <branch>

# Undo the desired commit
git revert <commit>

# Update the remote with the undo of the code
git push origin <branch>
```